# Connection reset by peer error while downloading video

Tags: shell, download, sh, youtube-dl

I have written a shell script to download video and do some operations. I'm using youtube-dl because I have a web page URL and need to download a video from that page. The script is

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /media/user/path/home/user/Videos/X
youtube-dl http://someUrl.com/somePath
#Do other operations
```

The video starts downloading and after some time shows `ERROR: unable to download video data: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`.

I tried running this command from the Ubuntu terminal. When I rerun the same command, video downloading resumes and stops again after few seconds/minutes. Is there some way where I can automatically re run the same command until the video has been downloaded? How do I catch this error and run the `youtube-dl` command recursively??

For reference I ran the command in terminal, have shown the terminal output below:

```
user@user-ThinkPad-T430:/media/user/path/home/user/Videos/X$ youtube-dl http://someUrl.com/somePath
[generic] somePath: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] somePath: Downloading webpage
[generic] somePath: Extracting information
[download] Resuming download at byte 79260669
[download] Destination:   someVideo - someUrl.-somePath.mp4
[download]  42.2% of 185.01MiB at 18.13KiB/s ETA 01:40:45ERROR: unable to download video data: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
user@user-ThinkPad-T430:/media/user/path/home/user/Videos/X$ youtube-dl http://someUrl.com/somePath
[generic] somePath: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] somePath: Downloading webpage
[generic] somePath: Extracting information
[download] Resuming download at byte 81777461
[download] Destination:   someVideo - someUrl.-somePath.mp4
[download]  44.3% of 185.01MiB at 21.68KiB/s ETA 01:21:12ERROR: unable to download video data: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Also tell me if there is any other alternate way.

Comment: You want us to debug your script, which you didn't show?

Comment: Edited the Question. I've shown the required parts of the script.

Comment: I voted up - good luck.